# tool/script to visit all pages in an ASP.NET project?

Tags: asp.net, automated-tests

Does anybody know of a tool, script, package, whatever that I can use to visit all pages in an ASP.NET Webforms web application project? (we aren't using any MVC functionality)

Preferably, I would like to be able to generate a list of URLs to hit, edit the list so I can add some query string params, hit all the pages in the list, and collect HTTP response codes: (200, 404, 500, 301, whatever).

Comment: Do you use webforms, mvc, etc?

Comment: Webforms. Edited question to clarify

Answer (score 0):

- Design time

Instead of using string literals for URLs in your application, define Url() methods in each page class like this:

```
public static string Url() { get { return "~/this_page.aspx"; } }
public static string Url(int ID) { get { return "~/this_page.aspx?id=" + ID; } }
```

Or list all URLs in a static class

```
public static class URL {
    public static string Login() { get { return "~/login.aspx"; } }
    public static string DisplayRecord(int recordID) 
        { get { return "~/display.aspx?id=" + recordID; } }
```

- Runtime

Use a web testing framework to crawl all links and edit the result. I [blogged](http://devio.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/crawling-all-links-with-selenium-and-nunit/) about one possible solution using Selenium.

Comment: Selenium is getting warmer, but I would rather work off of the information in the .csproj than crawl all links. I also want to be able to build and add to the list both programmatically and manually.

Answer (score 0):

I made a WinForms application that gets the pages that can be accessed from the .csproject and can open them by clicking a button.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace OpenAllPages
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static IList<string> Pages;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string xmlstring = ReadXml("TaskManager.csproj");
            Pages = ParseAllPages(xmlstring);
            pagesListBox.DataSource = Pages;
        }

        private string ReadXml(string location)
        {
            try
            {
                var myFile = new StreamReader(location);
                string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();
                myFile.Close();
                return myString;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("An error occurred: '{0}'", e.Message));
            }
            return null;
        }

        private IList<string> ParseAllPages(string xmlstring)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlstring);
            XPathNavigator nav = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator();
            XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable);
            manager.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");
            var elements = nav.Select("x:ItemGroup/x:Content", manager);

            var pageList = new List<string>();
            while (elements.MoveNext())
            {
                var page = elements.Current.GetAttribute("Include", "");
                if (page.EndsWith(".aspx"))
                    pageList.Add(page);
            }
            return pageList as IList<string>;
        }

        private string AddPagePrefix(string page)
        {
            return "http://localhost:8080/" + page;
        }

        private void openAllButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string page in Pages)
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", AddPagePrefix(page));
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is a link to the code](http://paste2.org/p/1608615)

You need to place the project file which contains the pages you want to open in the OpenAllPages project and set it's Copy to Output property to "Copy if newer".

I Form1_Load change TaskManager.csproj to the name of your project file.
And in:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", AddPagePrefix(page));
```

rename parameter to the executable of the browser you are using.